# Centralizar itens de uma navbar quando visualizada em desktop

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estou usando os códigos abaixo para criar uma navbar, mas gostaria de que, quando visualizado em desktop, os itens destacados em verde ficassem centralizados, porém em, quando visualizado em mobile, permanecesse exatamente como no gif.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código **CSS**

```
ul.bar-secondary {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #b5121b;
}

ul.bar-secondary li {float: left;}

ul.bar-secondary li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 300;
}

ul.bar-secondary li a:hover {background-color: #970008;}

ul.bar-secondary li.bar-secondary-icon {display: none;}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.bar-secondary li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  ul.bar-secondary li.bar-secondary-icon {
    float: right;
    padding-bottom: -5px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  ul.bar-secondary li.bar-secondary-icon a {
    padding-bottom: 17px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.bar-secondary.bar-secondary-responsive {position: relative;}
  ul.bar-secondary.bar-secondary-responsive li.bar-secondary-icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.bar-secondary.bar-secondary-responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.bar-secondary.bar-secondary-responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

Código **HTML**

```
<ul class="bar-secondary" id="bar-secondary">
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li class="bar-secondary-icon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="menu()">☰</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Código **JavaScript**

```
function menu() {
    var x = document.getElementById("bar-secondary");
    if (x.className === "bar-secondary") {
        x.className += " bar-secondary-responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "bar-secondary";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse seria o ideal pra vc?

```css
ul.bar-secondary {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #b5121b;
  text-align:center;
}

ul.bar-secondary li {display:inline;}

ul.bar-secondary li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 300;
}

ul.bar-secondary li a:hover {background-color: #970008;}

ul.bar-secondary li.bar-secondary-icon {display: none;}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.bar-secondary{text-align:left;}
  ul.bar-secondary li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  ul.bar-secondary li.bar-secondary-icon {
    float: right;
    padding-bottom: -5px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  ul.bar-secondary li.bar-secondary-icon a {
    padding-bottom: 17px;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="bar-secondary" id="bar-secondary">
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li class="bar-secondary-icon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="menu()">☰</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nano, achei o menu super bonitinho.

Primeiro, pra centralizar os seus ítens quando visualizado em desktop, você precisa dividir o espaço e preenchê-lo. Perceba que você tem 4 ítens, então essa divisão do espaço é de 25% pra cada, quando entrar mais algum ítem precisará diminuir esse tamanho pra caberem todos, por exemplo, com 5 ítens você vai precisar mudar o CSS para ser width de 20%(porque 100% / 5 = 20%) ao invés de 25%.
Então no seu CSS, acrescente `ul.bar-secondary li {float: left;  width:25%;  }`

Só que ao fazer isso, seu link não preenche o espaço todo, ponha ele pra pegar 100% do li, adicionando `width:100%` no seu `ul.bar-secondary li a`

```
ul.bar-secondary li a {
  width:100%;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

Só que ao fazer esses estilos acima o botãozinho ficou desconfigurado.
Marretei ele com !important pra ele não perder o tamanho certo (Não visualizei outra forma mantendo a mesma estrutura de classes):

```
.bar-secondary-icon, .bar-secondary-icon a { width:50px !important;  } 
.bar-secondary-icon a { padding-left:0px !important; text-align: center !important; }
```

Segue abaixo exemplo executável do seu código. Ao executar vai aparecer no tamanho de mobile, clique no link "Página toda" para ver como aparece em Desktop.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 
 <style>
 body { margin:0; padding:0;}
 
 ul.bar-secondary {
   list-style-type: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: #b5121b;
 }

 ul.bar-secondary li {float: left;  width:25%; }
 
 .bar-secondary-icon, .bar-secondary-icon a { width:50px !important;  } 
 .bar-secondary-icon a { padding-left:0px !important; text-align: center !important; } 
 

 ul.bar-secondary li a {
   width:100%; 
   display: inline-block;
   color: #f2f2f2;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 16px 0px;
   text-decoration: none;
   transition: 0.3s;
   font-size: 17px;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-weight: 300;
 }

 ul.bar-secondary li a:hover {background-color: #970008;}

 ul.bar-secondary li.bar-secondary-icon {display: none;}
 
 

 @media screen and (max-width:680px) 
 {
 
 ul.bar-secondary li a {
   text-align: left; 
   padding: 16px 14px;
   }
 
   ul.bar-secondary li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
   ul.bar-secondary li.bar-secondary-icon {
  float: right;
  padding-bottom: -5px;
  display: inline-block;
   }
   ul.bar-secondary li.bar-secondary-icon a {
  padding-bottom: 17px;
   }

   
   ul.bar-secondary.bar-secondary-responsive {position: relative;}
   ul.bar-secondary.bar-secondary-responsive li.bar-secondary-icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
   }
   ul.bar-secondary.bar-secondary-responsive li {
  float: none;
  display: inline;
   }
   ul.bar-secondary.bar-secondary-responsive li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
   }
   
 } 
 </style>
 
 <script>
 function menu() {
  var x = document.getElementById("bar-secondary");
  if (x.className === "bar-secondary") {
   x.className += " bar-secondary-responsive";
  } else {
   x.className = "bar-secondary";
  }
 } 
 </script> 
 
</head>
<body>

<ul class="bar-secondary" id="bar-secondary">
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li class="bar-secondary-icon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="menu()">☰</a>
  </li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Se esta resposta tiver ajudado a resolver seu problema marque como aceita e clique no triângulo pra cima para me dar pontos de reputação. Valew, obrigado. Qualquer coisa vamos nos falando nos comentários.

Editado:
Percebi que o ítem no mobile tava ficando torto e na versão desktop o padding estava ultrapassando a área do outro link. Acertei agora colocando padding da versão desktop para 16px 0px e padding da versão mobile para 16px 14px. (Ver código executável clicando no botão Executar e depois em "Página toda").